# Cross-Entropy Minimization - Extreme Code Performance

Tags: performance, time-limit-exceeded, matlab

I'm working on a multivariate cross-entropy minimization model (for more details about it, see [this paper](http://www.systemicrisk.ac.uk/sites/default/files/downloads/publications/dp-74-web.pdf), pp. 32-33). It's purpose is to adjust a prior multivariate distribution (in this case, a gaussian normal) with information on marginals coming from real observations.

The code at the end of the post represents my current implementation. The maths should have been correctly reproduced, unless I missed something critical during the review. The real problem I'm struggling to deal with is the performance of the code.

In the first part of the model, cumulative probabilities have to be computed over all the orthants of the distribution density. This process has a time complexity of `2^N`, where `N` is the number of entities included into the dataset. As long as the number of entities is less than `12`, everything is fast enough on my PC. With `20` entities, which is my current target, the model needs to run `mvncdf` over `1048576` combinations of orthants and this takes forever to finish.

I already improved the code a little bit by replacing the main `for` loop with a `parfor` loop. I acquired a huge performance gain by replacing the built-in `mvncdf` function with a user-made one.

I'm not very familiar with cross-entropy minimization models, so maybe there are math tricks I can use to simplify this calculation. Maybe the code can be vectorized even more. Well... any help or suggestion to improve the calculations speed is more than welcome!

```
clc();
clear();

% DATA

pods = [0.015; 0.02; 0.013; 0.007; 0.054; 0.034; 0.009; 0.065; 0.029; 0.205];
dts = [2.1; 2; 2.2; 2.4; 1.5; 1.8; 2.3; 1.5; 1.8; 0.8];

% Test of time complexity:
% pods = [pods; pods];
% dts = [dts; dts];

n = numel(pods);
c = eye(n);

k = 2^n;
kh = k / 2;
offsets = ones(n,1);

% G / BOUNDS FOR 1

g1 = combn([0 1],n);
bounds_1 = zeros(k,1);

parfor i = 1:k
    g1_c = g1(i,:).';
    lb = min([(-Inf * ~g1_c) dts],[],2);
    ub = max([(Inf * g1_c) dts],[],2);

    bounds_1(i) = mvncdf2(c,lb,ub);
end

% G / BOUNDS FOR 2:N

g2 = repmat({zeros(kh,n)},n,1);
bounds_2 = zeros(n,kh);

for i = 2:k
    g1_c = g1(i,:);
    b = bounds_1(i);

    for j = 1:n
        if (g1_c(j) == 0)
            continue;
        end           
            
        offset_j = offsets(j);

        g2t_j = g2{j};
        g2t_j(offset_j,:) = g1_c;
        g2{j} = g2t_j;

        bounds_2(j,offset_j) = b;

        offsets(j) = offset_j + 1;
    end

end

% SOLUTION

options = optimset(optimset(@fsolve),'Display','iter','TolFun',1e-08,'TolX',1e-08);
cns = [1; pods];
x0 = zeros(size(pods,1)+1,1);
lm = fsolve(@(x)objective(x,n,g1,bounds_1,g2,bounds_2,cns),x0,options);

stop = 1;

% Objective function of the model.
function p = objective(x,n,g1,bounds_1,g2,bounds_2,cns)

    mu = x(1);
    lambda = x(2:end);

    p = zeros(n + 1,1);

    for i = 1:numel(bounds_1)
        p(1) = p(1) + exp(-g1(i,:) * lambda) * bounds_1(i);
    end

    for i = 1:n
        g2_k = g2{i,1};
        
        for j = 1:size(bounds_2,2)
            p(i+1) = p(i+1) + exp(-g2_k(j,:) * lambda) * bounds_2(i,j);
        end
    end
    
    p = (exp(-1-mu) * p) - cns;

end

% All combinations of elements.
function [m,i] = combn(v,n)

    if ((fix(n) ~= n) || (n < 1) || (numel(n) ~= 1))
        error('Parameter N must be a scalar positive integer.');
    end

    if (isempty(v))
        m = [];
        i = [];
    elseif (n == 1)
        m = v(:); 
        i = (1:numel(v)).';
    else
        i = combn_local(1:numel(v),n);
        m = v(i);
    end
    
    function y = combn_local(v,n)

        if (n > 1)
            [y{n:-1:1}] = ndgrid(v);
            y = reshape(cat(n+1,y{:}),[],n);
        else
            y = v(:);
        end

    end
    
end

% Multivariate normal cumulative distribution function.
function y = mvncdf2(c,lb,ub)

    persistent options;

    if (isempty(options))
        options = optimset(optimset(@fsolve),'Algorithm','trust-region-dogleg','Diagnostics','off','Display','off','Jacobian','on');
    end
    
    n = size(c,1);

    [cp,lb,ub] = cholperm(n,c,lb,ub);
    d = diag(cp);

    if any(d < eps())
        y = NaN;
        return;
    end

    lb = lb ./ d;
    ub = ub ./ d;
    cp = (cp ./ repmat(d,1,n)) - eye(n);

    [sol,~,exitflag] = fsolve(@(x)gradpsi(x,cp,lb,ub),zeros(2 * (n - 1),1),options);

    if (exitflag ~= 1)
        y = NaN;
        return;
    end

    x = sol(1:(n - 1));
    x(n) = 0;
    x = x(:);
    
    mu = sol(n:((2 * n) - 2));
    mu(n) = 0;
    mu = mu(:);
    
    c = cp * x;
    lb = lb - mu - c;
    ub = ub - mu - c;

    y = exp(sum(lnpr(lb,ub) + (0.5 * mu.^2) - (x .* mu)));

end

function [cp,l,u] = cholperm(n,c,l,u)

    s2p = sqrt(2 * pi());

    cp = zeros(n,n);
    z = zeros(n,1);

    for j = 1:n
        j_seq = 1:(j - 1);
        jn_seq = j:n;
        j1n_seq = (j + 1):n;

        cp_off = cp(jn_seq,j_seq);
        z_off = z(j_seq);
        cpz = cp_off * z_off;

        d = diag(c);
        s = d(jn_seq) - sum(cp_off.^2,2);
        s(s < 0) = eps();
        s = sqrt(s);

        lt = (l(jn_seq) - cpz) ./ s;
        ut = (u(jn_seq) - cpz) ./ s;

        p = Inf(n,1);
        p(jn_seq) = lnpr(lt,ut);

        [~,k] = min(p);
        jk = [j k];
        kj = [k j];

        c(jk,:) = c(kj,:);
        c(:,jk) = c(:,kj);

        cp(jk,:) = cp(kj,:);
        l(jk) = l(kj);
        u(jk) = u(kj);

        s = c(j,j) - sum(cp(j,j_seq).^2);
        s(s < 0) = eps();

        cp(j,j) = sqrt(s);
        cp(j1n_seq,j) = (c(j1n_seq,j) - (cp(j1n_seq,j_seq) * (cp(j,j_seq)).')) / cp(j,j);

        cp_jj = cp(j,j);
        cpz = cp(j,j_seq) * z(j_seq);
        lt = (l(j) - cpz) / cp_jj;
        ut = (u(j) - cpz) / cp_jj;

        w = lnpr(lt,ut);
        z(j) = (exp((-0.5 * lt.^2) - w) - exp((-0.5 * ut.^2) - w)) / s2p;
    end

end

function [g,j] = gradpsi(y,L,l,u)

    d = length(u);
    d_seq = 1:(d - 1);

    x = zeros(d,1);
    x(d_seq) = y(d_seq);

    mu = zeros(d,1);
    mu(d_seq) = y(d:end);

    c = zeros(d,1);
    c(2:d) = L(2:d,:) * x;

    lt = l - mu - c;
    ut = u - mu - c;

    w = lnpr(lt,ut);
    pd = sqrt(2 * pi());
    pl = exp((-0.5 * lt.^2) - w) / pd;
    pu = exp((-0.5 * ut.^2) - w) / pd;
    p = pl - pu;

    dfdx = -mu(d_seq) + (p.' * L(:,d_seq)).';
    dfdm = mu - x + p;
    g = [dfdx; dfdm(d_seq)];

    lt(isinf(lt)) = 0;
    ut(isinf(ut)) = 0;

    dp = -p.^2 + (lt .* pl) - (ut .* pu);
    dl = repmat(dp,1,d) .* L;

    mx = -eye(d) + dl;
    mx = mx(d_seq,d_seq);
    
    xx = L.' * dl;
    xx = xx(d_seq,d_seq);

    j = [xx mx.'; mx diag(1 + dp(d_seq))];

end

function p = lnpr(a,b)

    p = zeros(size(a));

    a_indices = a > 0;
    
    if (any(a_indices))
        x = a(a_indices);
        pa = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));
        
        x = b(a_indices);
        pb = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        p(a_indices) = pa + log1p(-exp(pb - pa));
    end

    b_indices = b < 0;

    if (any(b_indices))
        x = -a(b_indices);
        pa = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        x = -b(b_indices);
        pb = (-0.5 * x.^2) - log(2) + reallog(erfcx(x / sqrt(2)));

        p(b_indices) = pb + log1p(-exp(pa - pb));
    end

    indices = ~a_indices & ~b_indices;

    if (any(indices))
        pa = erfc(-a(indices) / sqrt(2)) / 2;
        pb = erfc(b(indices) / sqrt(2)) / 2;
        p(indices) = log1p(-pa - pb);
    end

end
```

Comment: Have you ran the profiler? That should be your first step. Guessing as to what parts are slow is hard, we often guess wrong. Regarding your “micro-cache”, this is called memoization, and is trivial to add in MATLAB: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2018/07/05/memoize-functions-in-matlab/

Comment: Though the `parfor` will likely prevent the use of `memoize`.

Comment: Hi Cris, it's a pleasure to see you're still in here. I updated my answer with the last improvements I planned to include: memoization is no more required with the new way I use to perform computations. The new mvncdf function is blazing fast compared to the built-in one. Overall, the script performance now is much much better.

Comment: I optimized every single piece of code I could. And I run many profiling sessions. Yet, mvncdf takes about 80% / 90% of execution time. For 10 historical time series, it's just a matter of seconds and it's fine... the script starts taking a little bit too long at 13... with 20 it's still unfeasible, every rolling window (I have about 4500) takes like 30 minutes to finish. I'm really clueless about how to improve it further. Maybe big problems require big time and I reached a dead end?

Comment: It's hard to work out how to improve `mvncdf` without knowing what sort of inputs you're using (it could be fast and just being called a lot). I don't think you're going to get big improvements in speed, and the O(2^n) run time is unavoidable with this method. That being said, pre-allocating `x` and `mu` as `zeros(n,1)` would probably help a little. You are asking for a lot with so much uncommented code with mysterious variable names, I couldn't go through the rest of the code in much detail, or run it for larger `n` because I didn't know what inputs would be realistic to use.

Comment: And have you considered other optimisation methods for `fsolve` or picked the one you're using for a reason?